# UI Grid - Formatting Data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the new [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) (that is planned to replace ng-grid).
My data needs some formatting before it's displayed in the table. For instance, my server returns an attribute named "status" as a number, but I want to display it as a nice name.

If status=1 display "Todo", if status=2 display "Doing" etc.

How can this be done in UI Grid?

Comment: Please create a demo using plnkr or jsfiddle..so that we can try to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, add a cellTemplate to the column:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {field:'status', displayName: 'Status',cellTemplate: 'statusTemplate.html'}
];
```

The Template-File should look like this (COL_FIELD is the actual field):

```
<div style="text-align: center">{{COL_FIELD==1 ? 'Todo' : 'Doing'"}}</div>
```

Hope, you got the idea! :)

Answer (score 5):

The preferred method now is to use a cellFilter, rather than a custom template.  Custom templates are OK, but they impose more workload on upgrade - you have to check whether new features require modifications to your template.

There is a reasonable example of filters in the tutorials: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

Note the `cellFilter: 'mapGender'` on the gender column, and the filter itself defined further below in the tutorial:

```
.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is use CellTemplate with appScopeProvider:

```
  vm.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'status',
                cellTemplate: '<div>{{grid.appScope.formatStatus(row)}</div>'
            }
        ],
        appScopeProvider: {
            formatStatus: function (row) {
                return row.entity.status === 1 ? 'Todo' : 'Doing';
            },
        }
    }
```